Resume incrementing by one in another sheet that has blocks
As a lookup table, I have a list of names and URLs like this in a Google sheet:




Name
URL




Name 1
URL 1


Name 2
URL 2


Name 3
URL 3


Name 4
URL 4


Name 5
URL 5



Now, I would like to document observations about the objects in another sheet that is constructed like this:




Metadata
Observation




Name 1
Here, we discovered nothing special.






URL 1



Name 5
Here, we discovered nothing special.






URL 5




As can be seen, the counter takes the row number of the protocol entry instead of the next entry in the lookup table. Instead of Name and URL 5 it should be incremented by one only to Name and URL 2.
How can I get to automatically increment the counter by one even if a protocol entry is a block of several rows?


Here's one approach that furnishes the pattern:
=tocol(map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(a="",,{a,"⁤",b,"⁤"}))),1)



It works with the function INDIRECT:
Sample formula
=INDIRECT("Lookup_Sheet!A" & ((ROW() + 3) / 4)+1)

Lookup_Sheet!A2 is given to Protocol!A2.
Lookup_Sheet!A3 is given to Protocol!A5.
Lookup_Sheet!A3 is given to Protocol!A9.
and so on.
